# Neo4j Inconsistency During Backup "This node was not found in the expected index."

Tags: neo4j

I was getting the below inconsistency during backup

```
ERROR [o.n.c.ConsistencyCheckService] This node was not found in the expected index.
    Node[2317694,used=true,created=false,rel=12168688,prop=25684114,labels=Inline(0x1000000008:[8]),light]
    Inconsistent with: Index( id=13, name='constraint_d32ed228', type='UNIQUE BTREE', schema=(:Label[6] {PropertyKey[154]}), indexProvider='lucene+native-3.0', owningConstraint=15 ) []
2023-03-20 10:34:19.432+0000 WARN  [o.n.c.ConsistencyCheckService] Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
    Number of errors: 1
    Number of warnings: 0
    Number of inconsistent NODE records: 1
}
```

I followed the steps provided in [this article](https://support.neo4j.com/hc/en-us/articles/218047648-How-do-I-resolve-Consistency-Check-errors#:%7E:text=Node%20not%20found%20in%20the%20expected%20index).

The Backup was working fine temporarily but I started getting the same inconsistency error "**This node was not found in the expected index**" after a day. How do I solve this issue permanently.

I tried :
Rebuild the index store. To do this stop the database and then remove the entire directory of graph.db/schema/index. Restarting Neo4j to rebuild these files.

The backup was working fine temporarily without inconsistency but the inconsistency reappeared after a day causing backup failures again.